declaring a class and passing it as props to a child component followed by calling methods of this class
I declared a variable in data through a class, passed it as props to a child component, and called the class method in the child component, changing the variable in the class. Is it worth doing this in vue 2? On the one hand, this is a props mutation, on the other, vue does not swear at the props mutation

an example of what I mean https://plnkr.co/edit/NcnaATfD3zGiY7x2?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview
class User {
  name = 'initial name'

  setName (name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['user'],

  template: '<div><input @input="user.setName($event.target.value)"/></div>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'vue inst',
      user: new User()
    }
  },

  template: '<div>{{user.name}}<child :user="user"/></div>'
})

I thought that vue 2 would give an error about the prop mutation, but everything is fine. I can't find a direct answer to my question, but there is a feeling that this is a bad practice

You should be using Vue3 nowadays.

@kissu, why? You can still perfectly use vue2 :)

@Wimanicesir no: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-eol I mean, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot from Day 1, for sure go for it.

I could be wrong, but he ask to do something in vue2, not that he starts the project with it. If it already exists, why not. Can't imagine a feature missing that is now already in vue3. However just like your linked page says, there aren't security issues and there are ways to follow these up. I do agree though if he starts from scratch.

Doesn't look like it's a big project regarding the state of the question. Even if it is, a migration is still mandatory for OP's own sake.

Yes, you are right, this is not a project from scratch. But unfortunately, this is not a small project and it is not easy to switch from vue 2 to vue 3. I think the essence of my question could be attributed to any framework, but I am only familiar with vue 2

the code in the question is just an example of the situation that causes me to have a question that I can't find an answer to.
